# Identification of a duplicate not identifying duplicates

Tags: typescript

My app takes a string and applies to regex to extract a variety of things, an example:

```
let testString: string[] = ["${This one}$ and then ${That one}$ and also ${This one}$ and ${Sometimes Know[there,are,options]}$.. and sometimes ${Sometimes Know[there,are,options]}$ which repeat."]
```

And what I do is use a RegEx to find the names in between the $ $...

```
let splitRegex: RegExp = new RegExp('\\$\\{(.*?)\\}\\$', 'g');
let typeMatches: RegExpExecArray;
```

and then I want unique values, so:

```
let duplicates: string[] = [];

while(typeMatches = splitRegex.exec(testString)) { 

    let exists = duplicates.findIndex((temp: string) => temp === typeMatches[1]);

    if(exists === -1) {
        duplicates.push(typeMatches[1]); // add to duplicates array so if it comes up again it is ignored.
        // do stuff with the information...
    }

}
```

This all works... except for the '${Sometimes[there, are, options]}$' which sometimes has a duplicate which isn't picked up by the findIndex method.

Here is a [codepen with an example of this code in practice](https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/jOGrLBz?editors=0012). You will notice that annoyingly it works perfectly.

**Things I have done**

I have been working on this problem intermittently for a month or so I have tried:

- Normalizing the compared strings, trimming the compared string, adding a ''+ to the start to ensure they are strings, trying typeMatches[1].valueOf()
- I have tried storing typeMatches[1] in a different value and then comparing that.
- Printing the output of typeMatches and exists and duplicates to check if the strings look any different in ANY way, they do not.
- Using alternative methods than findIndex, such as stringName === array.find(...)

**An actual example**

Here is an actual example of a time when the code doesn't detect a duplicate. The emboldened parts are the undetected duplicates...

*String 1*

${v|Forename}$ ${v|Surname}$ has earned ${gn|him/her/them}$self [AnOrA] ${v|Grade}$ grade in ${g|Course Name}$ this **${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$** not performing quite as well as ${gn|he/she/they}$ did in the previous **${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$**..

*String 2*

${v|Forename}$ ${v|Surname}$ has earned ${gn|him/her/them}$self [AnOrA] ${v|Grade}$ grade in ${g|Course Name}$ this **${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$** performing on a par with how ${gn|he/she/they}$ did in the previous **${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$**.  .

*Side by side of the variables:*

- ${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$
- ${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$
- ${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$
- ${g|Time Period[semester,term]}$

*The typeMatches[1](https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/jOGrLBz?editors=0012) string value (the regex [1](https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/jOGrLBz?editors=0012) value)*

- First instance : g|Time Period[semester,term]
- Second instance: g|Time Period[semester,term]

*The objects that are created with this data*

```
{
    "identifier": "Time Period",
    "value": "",
    "options": [
        "semester",
        "term"
    ]
}
{
    "identifier": "Time Period",
    "value": "",
    "options": [
        "semester",
        "term"
    ]
}
```

And just in case it is useful, [here is a non-functional codepen](https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/dyVXzjX?editors=0010) of the actual function where this is a problem...

Comment: Why didn't you provide a working codepen for the problematic input? I updated the first codepen with the "string 1" and "string 2" you gave, and it works as expected - no duplicates.

Comment: Fair, but yes no problems. Its erratic. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.